# Optimize Union All SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

Could you help me optimize the following Union All Query?
Any idea where to start?
Details: 
SQL Plan shows

|   7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL         | DELAY_DATE             | 17533 |   171K|    25   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL         | VACANCY                | 25879 |   454K|   298   (1)| 00:00:04 |

|  16 |      MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN        |                        | 17533 |   273K|    28   (4)| 00:00:01 |

Are these potential issues?

```
 SELECT    delay_reason_desc, delay_start_date, delay_end_date, delay_reason_code
    FROM        delay_date dd
    LEFT JOIN   delay_reason dr
    ON          dr.delay_reason_id=dd.delay_reason_id
    LEFT JOIN   delay_interval di
    ON          di.delay_interval_id=dr.delay_interval_id
    LEFT JOIN   vacancy v
    ON          v.vacancy_id=dd.vacancy_id
    WHERE       dr.delay_reason_active_ind='Y'
    --AND         dd.vacancy_id=p_vacancy_id
    AND         delay_start_date >= vacancy_fpps_received_date
    AND         delay_end_date <= vacancy_open_date
    AND         delay_interval_code=1


UNION ALL
    SELECT    delay_reason_desc, delay_start_date, delay_end_date, delay_reason_code
    FROM        delay_date dd
    LEFT JOIN   delay_reason dr
    ON          dr.delay_reason_id=dd.delay_reason_id
    LEFT JOIN   delay_interval di
    ON          di.delay_interval_id=dr.delay_interval_id
    LEFT JOIN   vacancy v
    ON          v.vacancy_id=dd.vacancy_id
    WHERE       dr.delay_reason_active_ind='Y'
    --AND         dd.vacancy_id=p_vacancy_id
    AND         delay_start_date >= vacancy_open_date
    AND         delay_end_date <= vacancy_closed_date
    AND         delay_interval_code=2
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on these tables?

Comment: You should try to get into the habit of prefixing all columns with table name aliases. It's reasonably clear in this case which tables the columns are members of, but it's more robust and an aid to reading to include them.

Answer (score 6):

How about this -- could be as much as twice as fast:

```
SELECT    delay_reason_desc, delay_start_date, delay_end_date, delay_reason_code
    FROM        delay_date dd
    LEFT JOIN   delay_reason dr
    ON          dr.delay_reason_id=dd.delay_reason_id
    LEFT JOIN   delay_interval di
    ON          di.delay_interval_id=dr.delay_interval_id
    LEFT JOIN   vacancy v
    ON          v.vacancy_id=dd.vacancy_id
    WHERE       dr.delay_reason_active_ind='Y'

    AND ((delay_start_date >= vacancy_fpps_received_date
         AND delay_end_date <= vacancy_open_date
         AND delay_interval_code=1)
    OR  (delay_start_date >= vacancy_open_date
          AND delay_end_date <= vacancy_closed_date
          AND delay_interval_code=2))
```

Comment: Elapsed: 00:00:00.234 VS Elapsed: 00:00:00.046  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
create index delay_reason on delay_reason_id
create index delay_interval on delay_interval_id
create index vacancy on vacancy_id

create index delay_date on delay_reason_active_ind, delay_interval_code
```

Then call the SQL suggested by @Hogan.