# Optimize a Repeating Union All SSMS Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, union-all, ssms-2016

I'm creating a report that will get uploaded to QuickBooks. I have to UNION ALL 7 queries due to a single calculation change in each one. Below is an example of the first two queries:

```
SELECT
    Clients.Id
    ,@CNumber as 'Check Number'
    ,@TDate as 'Transac Date'
    ,CONCAT(@Memo, 'Debt') as 'Memo'
    ,Compensation.Payment as 'Amount'

FROM Compensation

    JOIN Clients on Id = Compensation.ClientId

UNION ALL

SELECT
    Clients.Id
    ,@CNumber as 'Check Number'
    ,@TDate as 'Transac Date'
    ,CONCAT(@Memo, 'Insurance') as 'Memo'
    ,InsuranceInvoices.WeeklyAmount

FROM InsuranceInvoices
```

**Is there any way to eliminate the need to repeat the Clients.Id, @CNumber, @TDate, CONCAT(@Memo, Variable) for every single union?**

For the CONCAT(@MEMO, variable) as 'Memo", I can perhaps create an array and insert on each new iteration of Union ALL (don't know if that's even possible).

Where I'm stuck is, not sure how to create a loop which iterates the first 4 columns, on each new calculation of 'Amount'.

This is solely for the purposes of optimization/code readability. The query works and it's not all that slow. However, it's 155 lines long and I wonder if the next time I do something similar I can try doing so differently.

**What I've researched so far**: The following Stack Overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162670/optimize-union-all-sql) is somewhat similar, however, it's not using different 'FROM' Tables. The data is coming from a single table. My data is coming from 4 tables. Below a sample of two queries from the same table:

```
    SELECT
        Clients.Id
        ,@CNumber as 'Check Number'
        ,@TDate as 'Transac Date'
        ,CONCAT(@Memo, 'Debt') as 'Memo'
        ,Compensation.PaybackAmount as 'Amount'

    FROM Compensation

        JOIN Clients on Id = Compensation.ClientId

    WHERE
        Compensation.Week = @TrailingWeekEnd

UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Clients.Id
        ,@CNumber as 'Check Number'
        ,@TDate as 'Transac Date'
        ,CONCAT(@Memo, 'Vehicle') as 'Memo'
        ,Compensation.VDAccumulation as 'Amount'

    FROM ContractorSettlements

        JOIN Clients on Id = Compensation.ClientId

    WHERE
        Compensation.Week = @TrailingWeekEnd
```

If this is a bad question, my apologies. In my mind, I imagine this working within a loop but I honestly don't know how to optimize it. If there is any more info I can provide, please let me know.

Comment: This `FROM` clause makes no sense:  `FROM Compensation.Payment JOIN Clients on Id = Compensation.ClientId`.  Fix the code in your question.

Comment: Edited, thank you. I had to modify the query prior to posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite of the wrong syntax you have in the query but you can use the following

**Explanation**

1. Query only the data required to extract from the tables
2. Differentiate the data by adding a type for each table like `Debt` and `Vehicle`
3. Combine the result with the parameters you want

Query

```
;with report as(
    select [Id] = ClientId,
           [Amount] = PaybackAmount,
           [Type] = 'Debt'
    Compensation c 
    where c.Week = @TrailingWeekEnd
    union all
    select ClientId,
           VDAccumulation,
           'Vehicle'
    from ContractorSettlements c
    where c.Week = @TrailingWeekEnd
)
select Id,
       [Check Number] = @CNumber,
       [Transac Date] = @TDate,
       [Memo] = Concat(@Memo,[Type]),
       Amount
from report
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you! In regards to the error, I had to modify the query prior to posting. This method eliminated about 50 lines or so.